# What is the difference between rw+ and r+

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, python-2.x

I stumbled onto this stackoverflow question while doing some file IO: [Confused by python file mode "w+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208206/confused-by-python-file-mode-w)

> - `r` for reading
> - `w` for writing
> - `r+` opens for reading and writing (cannot truncate a file)
> - `w+` for writing and reading (can truncate a file)
> - `rb+` reading or writing a binary file
> - `wb+` writing a binary file
> - `a+` opens for appending

Note the `r+` cannot truncate a file. So I was looking for something that could truncate the file after reading it which led me to another SO link: [Python truncate lines as they are read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525272/python-truncate-lines-as-they-are-read)

I saw that they used a different mode, `rw+`, which was not documented. From how it was used in the answer, I guessed it meant "open for reading, writing and truncating but do not truncate on open".

I later tested this mode and it seems that it was removed in Python 3, hence throwing a `ValueError` when used:

Python 2:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "rw+")
text = f.read()
f.truncate(0)
f.close()
```

Python 3:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "rw+")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode
```

However, I needed a file mode in Python 3 that can truncate as well as read but not truncate on open. So, after a bit more testing, I found that `r+` can actually truncate in both Python 2 and 3.

Python 2:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "r+")
text = f.read()
f.truncate(0)
f.seek(0, 0)
print f.read()
f.close()
```

Will print out nothing.

Python 3:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "r+")
text = f.read()
f.truncate(0)
f.seek(0, 0)
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

Will also print out nothing.

My question is, if both `r+` and `rw+` can truncate, what are the differences between them in Python 2?

Answer (score 3):

On Linux at least, there's no difference as far as I can tell. Here's a test script

```
f1 = open('f1', 'r+')
f2 = open('f2', 'rw+')
f3 = open('f3', 'w+')
```

and its corresponding OS syscalls (using strace); tested on python 2.7.9.

```
open("f1", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)          = 3
open("f2", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)          = 4
open("f3", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = 5
```

See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html for more details on the file access and creation flags.

It's not accurate to say a file object opened with 'r+' *cannot* be used to truncate a file - it just doesn't do so at the point the file is opened.